# oracle sequence with entity framework core throws ORA-02287

Tags: entity-framework-core, oracle.manageddataaccess

I've got an ASP .net 6 project with EF core. I need a sequenced value outside of tables, keys, etc. So I'm doing this:

```
public class GenericInt { public int IntValue { get; set; } }
public DbSet<GenericInt> GenericInts { get; set; }
...
var qresult = await ctx.GenericInts.FromSqlRaw("select MYSCHEMA.MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL from dual").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

This throws:

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException
HResult=0x80004005
Message=ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here
Source=Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver
```

Why?
How to repair this?

Comment: Use `ToListAsync()` or don't use EF in the first place. You can't use `NEXTVAL` in a subquery. `FromSqlRaw()` is used to create a *subquery* that's combined with the operators added after it to produce the final query. `FirstOrDefault` will create and execute something like `select * from (select MYSCHEMA.MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL from dual) fetch next 1 rows only`. You can use Dapper to execute SQL and map the results in a single line

Comment: EF is an ORM and `GenericInts` is a *very* strange name for an entity. This suggests you're trying to use a DbContext for simple result mapping. That's *not* a good idea - a DbContext is a Unit-of-Work so it tracks entities. There's an extra overhead involved when it reads data too.

Answer (score 0):

Panagiotis Kanavos gave the key point:

**FirstOrDefault constructs a subquery.**

(And sequence cannot be used in subqueries, it's a known limitation.)

There was another problem with my original EF call, so the working lines are:

```
var qresult = await ctx.GenericInts.FromSqlRaw("select MYSCHEMA.MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL as intval from dual").ToListAsync();
int seqValue = qresult[0].IntValue;
```

(The advice of mis-using EF may also be considered.)